# Activity Stream with Spring Boot and Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, activity-streams

I'm starting on a Discuss https://disqus.com like Spring Boot application.

- A user can create circles (Communities/Group)
- A user can subscribe/unsubscribe to/from a circle.
- User can post document/image/video to a circle or individual user
- Each user have an inbox feed

Designed for high user activities with high scalability requirement, I'm closing down to Activity Streams (W3C Activity Stream 2.0) with Kafka as the backbone.

I have a distributed cloud native Microservice architecture already set up (Spring config server, API gateway, Eureka Discovery) with Angular 2.0 frontend.

I'm researching on Kafka and would like your views on how I should go about the architecture and design to meet my requirements.

To be specific:

1. The Kafka producer is responsible for converting activities send via HTTP into POJO based on Activity 2.0 specification and publish it to Kafka. How should I design the publisher to handle, say a million of messages per second.
2. Consumers are different services, such as Circle Service, Recommendation Service, User service, and so on. My naive thinking is to make these services subscribe to a topic and pull out only those messages they are interested in. For example, if a user posts to a circle, the Circle Service will use it to make copies and distribute to all users of that circle. Another concern here. If a circle contains, say 1000 users, what will be the best approach to make the copies?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It will be better if you can mention specific areas in 'design' and 'architecture' you need inputs on, otherwise it will hard to just comment on something as open ended as this

Comment: @Abhishek edited the question to make it more specific